# Retrieve deep link data from Branch.io on the web

Tags: api, deep-linking, branch.io, deeplink

I've created a Branch.io link: fight.offtherecord.com/alexg. This link has deep data associated with it, for example (i.e. alias = Alexg, userId = 375, etc.). Branch.io stores this data on their end.

When I load this link in my browser, from a desktop, I end up with the following in my address bar: "https://offtherecord.com/?_branch_match_id=224695141967923130".

How do I get access to the data stored alongside the link? I don't see any APIs available. I do see this GET API: 
     https://api.branch.io/v1/url?branch_key=&url=http://fight.offtherecord.com/alexg
But that requires having the original link that was entered, as opposed to what I end up with in my address bar.

I've looked through their Web SDK but came up empty.

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing you're creating a [custom text me the app page](https://dev.branch.io/features/text-me-the-app/guide/#sendsms-example), where you want to customize your page for the link. I found that when performing the branch.init call, you can get all the data. There are also calls like branch.data(callback) and branch.first(callback) [see their doc](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/Smart-App-Banner-Deep-Linking-Web-SDK#initbranch_key-options-callback).

just replace their

```
branch.init('YOUR-BRANCH-KEY');
```

with

```
branch.init('YOUR-BRANCH-KEY',function(err, data) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        });
```

and you'll have the data. You can't test this locally, it has to be at the URL that's in the branch settings.

Comment: your comment helped me but doesn't answer the origin question

Comment: @mcabe my answer gives you the data on the page with the resolved link. Seems you're saying you want to get the data with just the resolved uri and no branch key? If you have the branch key, you should be able to do the same thing as above. If you don't it seems like you're trying to see the data in someone else's links? Or am I missing the point?

Comment: I was just about to edit my comment! I understood your answer to mean that using the init one would get all the data bundles,  and since I was on localhost I couldn't test it.  But after having read through the docs very carefully and rereading you answer I realized you were indeed correct :)